# Why do some yeoman scaffolds take up so much space? How to optimize?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I noticed some generators take up quite a bit of space. For instance, `generator-angular`, after a fresh scaffold, takes up about 312MB. If I have ten Angular projects, that's quite a bit of space wasted.

```
 12K    Gruntfile.js
4.0K    README.md
 88K    app
4.0K    bower.json
3.9M    bower_components
308M    node_modules
4.0K    package.json
 16K    test
312M    total
```

Is there some way to have all my Angular projects reference a common set of node modules, so I can have a single folder that's 300MB, rather than ten of them?

Answer (score 0):

A solution to minimize the memory footprint of the application is to install the node dependencies globaly with npm install >dependency< --global

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: I tried that. As a test, I did `npm install -g grunt`, and yet `grunt` was still installed locally in the project's folder.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but maybe it installs dependencies anyways when they are in the package.json file. Can you test if it still works when you delete the grund folder in der node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

When running your npm install do this:

```
`npm install -g [the-module-name]`
```

Doing this should save the reference globally, meaning that all other project you create, won't have to put the module into its own folder, but simply reference to the folder where the module has been saved globally.

***BEWARE:*** This could create another problem, since the module need a module, which need a module, and so on. This gave me problems when deleting a project, since the file path seems to be to long for a Windows machine.

There's an easy fix here though: http://blog.ardill.com/2013/06/path-too-long-when-trying-to-delete.html

Comment: See my comment on the other answer. Installing something globally doesn't seem to help.